# firebase admin sdk listener callback not working

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

i am using firebase java sdk for server backend code . i am using saving Async call and waiting on that too but the single value event listeners which were added on database are not working. I even tried googleCompleteableFutureApi to wait for async call to complete but still callback piece not executing.
see code below:-

```
package com.stocknap;

import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.Builder;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

//import com.google.firebase.tasks.TaskCompletionSource;

public enum Firebase {
    INSTANCE;

    FirebaseApp firebaseApp;


    public void initilizeFirebaseApp(ConfigLoader configReader) {

        CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final AtomicInteger message1 = new AtomicInteger(0);
        InputStream firebaseSecret = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ServiceAccount.json");
        final GoogleCredentials credentials;
        try {
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(firebaseSecret);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error while reading Firebase config file." + e.toString());
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        Map<String, Object> auth = new HashMap<>();
        auth.put("uid", "my_resources");

        FirebaseOptions options = new Builder()
                .setConnectTimeout(1000)
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(auth)
                .setDatabaseUrl(configReader.getFirebaseDatabaseURL())
                .setStorageBucket(configReader.getFirebaseStorageBucket())
                .setProjectId(configReader.getFirebseProjectId())
                .build();

        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);


        System.out.println(firebaseApp.getName());
        //System.out.println(firebaseApp.getName());
        // Use the shorthand notation to retrieve the default app's service
        FirebaseAuth defaultAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseDatabase defaultDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


        // The app only has access as defined in the Security Rules
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference("/analyst_profiles");


        DateTime dt = new DateTime(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()), java.util.TimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println(dt.getValue());
        //test data push
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data
        AnalystProfiles analystProfilesObjTemp = new AnalystProfiles("test2", Long.toString(dt.getValue()), "dsds", "ds", "ds",
                "dsa2323", "32ddss232");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                AnalystProfiles post = dataSnapshot.getValue(AnalystProfiles.class);
                System.out.println(post);
                //done.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }


        });


        CompletableFuture<String> welcomeText = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                ref.push().setValueAsync(analystProfilesObjTemp).get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error while waiting for future", e);
            }
            return "ok";

        }).thenApply(x -> {
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println("Listeners code is not executing");
            return x;
        });


        done.countDown();
        try {
            System.out.println(welcomeText.get());
            done.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    public void testdataLoad() {

        // The app only has access as defined in the Security Rules
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference("/analyst_profiles");


        DateTime dt = new DateTime(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()), java.util.TimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println(dt.getValue());
        //test data push
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data
        AnalystProfiles analystProfilesObjTemp = new AnalystProfiles("test2", Long.toString(dt.getValue()), "dsds", "ds", "ashutsh",
                "dsa2323", "32ddss232");

        CompletableFuture<String> welcomeText = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                ref.push().setValueAsync(analystProfilesObjTemp).get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error while waiting for future", e);
            }
            return "ok";

        }).thenApply(x -> {
            System.out.println(x);
            return x;
        });



        try {
            System.out.println(welcomeText.get());

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Main driver program:-

```
package com.stocknap;

import com.zerodhatech.kiteconnect.KiteConnect;
import com.zerodhatech.kiteconnect.kitehttp.SessionExpiryHook;
import com.zerodhatech.kiteconnect.kitehttp.exceptions.KiteException;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * Created by sujith on 7/10/16.
 * This class has example of how to initialize kiteSdk and make rest api calls to place order, get orders, modify order, cancel order,
 * get positions, get holdings, convert positions, get instruments, logout user, get historical data dump, get trades
 */
public class MainStockNap {

    static PropertyFileReader propReader;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws KiteException, IOException {
        try {
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            KiteConnect kiteConnect = new KiteConnect("kbnbnmbnmbnm8877bvbv");

            // Set userId
            kiteConnect.setUserId("");

            //Enable logs for debugging purpose. This will log request and response.
            kiteConnect.setEnableLogging(true);

            // Get login url
            String url = kiteConnect.getLoginURL();

            // Set session expiry callback.
            kiteConnect.setSessionExpiryHook(new SessionExpiryHook() {
                @Override
                public void sessionExpired() {
                    System.out.println("session expired");
                }
            });


            System.out.println(args.toString());
            // reading params
            if (args.length == 0){
                System.out.println("config file path not given");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else{
                //this.setConfigFile(args[2]);
                propReader = new PropertyFileReader(args[0]);

            }

            //PropertyFileReader prop = new PropertyFileReader();

           // Properties prop = Main.getConfigFile();
           // System.out.println(prop.getConfigFile().getProperty("API_SECRET"));

            ConfigLoader configObj= ConfigLoader.getInstance();
            configObj.setConfigSource(propReader);
            System.out.println("---------zerodha properties----------------");
            System.out.println(configObj.get_CLIENT_ID());
            System.out.println(configObj.get_API_SECRET());
            System.out.println(configObj.get_APITOKEN());
            System.out.println(configObj.get_PUBLICTOKEN());
            System.out.println(configObj.get_APIKey());

            System.out.println("---------firebase properties----------------");
            System.out.println(configObj.getFirebaseAPIKey());
            System.out.println(configObj.getFirebaseAuthDomain());
            System.out.println(configObj.getFirebaseMessagingSenderId());
            System.out.println(configObj.getFirebseProjectId());
            System.out.println(configObj.getFirebaseStorageBucket());
            System.out.println(configObj.getFirebaseDatabaseURL());

            Firebase.INSTANCE.initilizeFirebaseApp(configObj);
            Firebase.INSTANCE.testdataLoad();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You code has a lot going on, and it's not possible to figure out what you expected to see. I slightly modified it into the following test case. This seems to work fine:

```
  @Test
  public void initilizeFirebaseApp() throws Exception {
    CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
        .getInstance()
        .getReference("/analyst_profiles");

    DatabaseReference newChild = ref.push();

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          if (child.getKey().equals(newChild.getKey())) {
            System.out.println("New data: " + child.getValue());
            done.countDown();
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });

    Object analystProfilesObjTemp = ImmutableMap.of("key", "value");
    newChild.setValueAsync(analystProfilesObjTemp).get();

    try {
      done.await();
      System.out.println("Listener hit for new child: " + newChild.getKey());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I get the output:

```
New data: {key=value}
Listener hit for new child: -LXW0CS2jFjphnoFKQkb
```